# Randomizing a given text

Tags: luatex, algorithms

It sounds stupid, but it's useful to me. I want to randomize words. To input a text, and to get an output with the same words, in random order. I have no idea how to begin with, though. Therefore I cannot even provide a MWE.

Can somebody tell me which package could I use in order to:

- not to have to introduce the text as a list separated by commas
- get really a randomized text
- that the sequence `word,` and in general `word[punctuation-sign]` also be randomly separated

Comment: Have a look at the [`chickenize` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chickenize)

Comment: I was thinking of the package as providing mechanisms to help implement what you request.

Comment: So you want to scan the text, separate words and punctuation, put them into a list using \expandafter\def\csname somename\thecounter\endcsname{word}, then randomly reassemble them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a small demonstration using LuaTeX, let it be a starting point for further explorations.

- The code changes some commands, e.g. `\bf` to `\textbf` for faster text manipulation (the `%b` operator in Lua) as I wished to have some words formatted at a TeX level.
- It also changes spaces to `} \command` sequence in formatted code, e.g. we are getting from a `\textbf{1 2 3}` sequence a new one, `\text{1} \text{2} \text{3}`.
- After that the code splits whole string by space and saves terms into a Lua table.
- That table is hashed and therefore it looks randomly ordered when words are printed. *Update 1:* I'm not 100% sure that hashed is equal to (pseudo-)randomly chosen, therefore I used a classical algorithm with the help of the `math.random` function and removing items from a table until that table is empty.
- At a TeX level there is a `\randomize` command, we call it when needed.
- *Update 2:* I have also implemented some basic manipulation with punctuations: those (only .,!?) behave like words and in the postprocessing phase we delete some extra spaces.

I enclose the code and a preview of the result, the first paragraph is processed and coloured for easier reading, the second paragraph is an original text. We run `lualatex mal-text.tex`.

```
% lualatex mal-text.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
math.randomseed(321) -- Are we getting the some output?

-- Preparations for minor changes.
format={ "\\textbf", "\\textit" }
change={ ["it"]="\\textit", ["bf"]="\\textbf" }
malcomma="[%.,!%?]+"

-- The core function we call every time when
-- we use the \randomize command in TeX.
function random()
text=tex.toks[0] -- Take parameter from TeX.
words={} -- initialize/clear the variable with previously parsed words
print("Processing: "..text)

-- Change \bf to \textbf for faster searching at a Lua level.
for search, modify in pairs(change) do
  text=unicode.utf8.gsub(text, "{\\"..search.." ", modify.."{")
end -- for, modify

-- Let punctuations behave like words.
-- I am choosing only some basic ones for demonstration.
text=unicode.utf8.gsub(text, "("..malcomma..")", " %1")

-- Let's delete spaces after commands.
text=unicode.utf8.gsub(text, "(\\[%a]-) ", "%1")
for _,term in pairs(format) do -- Focus on defined terms only.
   text=unicode.utf8.gsub(text, term.."(%b{})", -- Find that part.
   function(s) -- Change spaces to commands, e.g. \textbf{a b c} to \textbf{a} \textf{b} \textbf{c}.
      s=unicode.utf8.gsub(s, "%s+", "} "..term.."{")
      toreturn=term..s -- Add original command to the string,
      -- print(toreturn) -- print byproduct, if necessary,
      return toreturn -- and return it to the gsub.
   end -- function, s
   ) -- end of gsub
end -- for, term

-- Store data, they will be hashed at a Lua level.
for word in unicode.utf8.gmatch(text, "[%S]+") do
   -- print("..."..word.."...") -- Words we process.
   -- words[word]=word -- Is hashed equal to randomized? I assume not, therefore there is a classical example.
   table.insert(words,word) -- Storing one text element.
   end -- for, word

-- Print all words back in TeX, even with punctuation, 
-- but the terms are hashed, therefore it looks like 
-- randomly choosen data.
-- An old example...
--[[ for _, selected in pairs(words) do
   tex.print(selected)
   end -- for, selected]]

-- A new example, that's almost a classical algorithm...
backup=words -- backuping data, just in case
malstring=""

while #words~=0 do -- print table until that is empty
   selected=math.random(#words) -- randomly pick number between 1 and number of elements in the table words
   malstring=malstring..words[selected].." " -- print that element
   table.remove(words,selected) -- and delete it
end -- repeat that process until that table is empty

-- Postprocessing due to punctuations, e.g. > . . <. Delete that extra space.
malstring=unicode.utf8.gsub(malstring, " ("..malcomma..")", "%1") -- unformatted punctuations
malstring=unicode.utf8.gsub(malstring, " (\\%a+{"..malcomma.."})", "%1") -- formatted punctuations
malstring=unicode.utf8.gsub(malstring, "%s+$", "") -- remove ending spaces
-- print(malstring)

-- Print the result in a document.
tex.sprint(malstring)

end -- function, random
\end{luacode*}

% Some background in TeX, send parameter to Lua.
% Let's change colour of the randomized text for easier checking the results.
\def\randomize#1{%
   \toks0{#1}% Saving parameter for later load.
   \begingroup\color{blue}% Change a colour within a group.
   \directlua{random()}% Calling Lua.
   \endgroup% End of the group, change of colour.
   }% End of the command \randomize.

% An example of use.
% Definition of text + printing it.
\def\maltext{%
Regular text. \randomize{Text to be randomized. Next sentence to be used.} Common text, the middle part. \randomize{Next section \textit{of the text, middle part,} ending word.} The paragraph ends here. \randomize{1 2 {\bf 3 4 5 6 7 8} 9 0}. One last change: \randomize{a b c d e f g h A B C D E F G H}.}
\maltext

% Show me the original text.
\def\randomize#1{#1}
\maltext
\end{document}
```

[image: an example of the code: randomizing word selection]

Comment: Your work is just amazing! :)